# Idiomatic way of using StringBuilder in kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, idioms

I often write pretty complex toString() methods and this question is always bothering me - which variant is more clear to read. Following examples are simplified, usually there are a lot of conditionals, so single liners are not fit.

1) like in plain java:

```
val sb = StringBuilder()
sb.append(data)
val string = sb.toString()
```

2) apply + toString() - not pretty yeah?

```
val string = StringBuilder().apply {
    append(data)
}.toString()
```

3) run + toString() last statement also is not superb

```
val string = StringBuilder().run {
    append(data)
    toString()
}
```

4) ??

Comment: You're asking .... which is more clear *to read*? ... How is that question answerable?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/build-string.html. It's just `val s = buildString { append(data) }`

Comment: thanks @dyukha - that is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

@dyukha answer is 100% best choice: 
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/build-string.html

It's just

```
val s = buildString { append(data) }
```

Comment: You can also use chained form `StringBuilder().append("first").append("second").toString()`

Comment: in description: "usually there are a lot of conditionals, so single liners are not fit"

Comment: Depending on your usecase, making a collection of strings and then joining to string is a viable alternative. The advantage is that you don't need to call `append`. For example: `listOf("One. Data: $data", "Two", "Three",).joinToString(separator = "; ")`